# Solving modulo equations programmatically

Tags: c#, algorithm, modulo

My goal is to implement a (simple) check digit alglorithm as described [Here](http://www.azalea.com/white-papers/upc-barcode-check-digit/)

My implemantion is the following but I am not sure if it is optimal:

```
 private int CheckDigit(string SevenDecimal)
        {
            ///Get UPC check digit of a 7-digit URI
            ///Add odd and multiply by 3 =Odds
            ///Add even =Evens
            ///Add Odds+Evens=sum
            ///Check digit is the number that makes Sum divisble by 10
            int Odds = 0;
            int Evens = 0;
            int sum = 0;
            int index = 0;
            foreach (char digit in SevenDecimal)
            {
                index++;
                int Digit = int.Parse(digit.ToString());

                if (index % 2 == 0)
                {
                    Evens +=Digit;
                }
                else
                {
                    Odds +=Digit;
                }
            }
            Odds = Odds * 3;
            sum = Odds + Evens;


            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)  ///Brute force way check for better implementation
            {
                int Localsum;
                Localsum = sum + i;
                if (Localsum % 10 == 0)
                {
                    return i;
                }
            }
           return -1;//error;                
        }
```

My main concern is in the final for loop which as I describe is totallly brute.
Is there a better way to obtaining the check digit?

More precisely which is the best way to solve programmatically, the equation:

```
(sum+x)%10=0  //solve for x
```

Comment: Is not: 10 - ( x % 10 )   ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find "how much `i` you have to add to make the last digit of a number a 0", you can subtract from 10:

```
int checkDigit = (10 - (sum % 10)) % 10;
```

The second modulo is used for the special case when `sum % 10 == 0`, because 10 - 0 = 10

Comment: Great...that's exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You are asking the wrong question. The expression is not one of equivalence thus `x` is not a *value*. The solution is that `x` is an infinite number of values each of which correctly solve the equation. As such you don't really want to `solve for x` but just check if `x` is in this solution space. You can check this simply with:

```
remainder = base - (sum % base)
```

You can then test if `x` sums up to the remainder with:

```
if (x % base === base - (sum % base))
{
    // (sum + x) % base = 0 is true
}
```

Replace `base` with `10`and you'll have it.

Comment: Actually you have a point, but since we are in the [0,10] space (check digit is a decimal digit) there is always only 1 solution